# How to encrypt/decrypt text from file with php?

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography

How to encrypt/decrypt text from file with php?

Comment: Which version of PHP? What modules do you have compiled into your PHP? What type of encryption?

Comment: Any version of PHP.Any version of encryptions.Any modules

Comment: You can look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655691/php-pear-encrypting-with-cryptcbc-decrypting-with-perls-cbc

Comment: Any version of encryption?  Allow me to introduce you to my friend, ROT13...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you have mcrypt module compiled with your PHP:

Comment: Keys should be at least 16 characters long

Comment: WARNING : mcrypt_encrypt was remove since PHP 7.2 (https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use the [mcrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php) php library. It supports a wide variety of encryption schemes. You will probaly need to do a recompile. If you don't already have this exstension, you can install [pgp](http://www.gnupg.org/), and shell out to the executable to run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic DES encryption

```
<?php

$key = 'yourSecretKey';
$plain_text = pkcs5_pad(file_get_contents('yourFile.txt'));

/* Open module, and create IV */
$td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
$key = substr($key, 0, mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($td));
$iv_size = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);

/* Initialize encryption handle */
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);

/* Encrypt data */
$encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $plain_text);
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
file_put_contents('yourFile.txt.enc', $encrypted);
```

Comment: what about decryption?