# Perl & Ruby exchange AES encrypted information

Tags: ruby, perl, cryptography, aes, rijndael

What is the equivalent to Crypt::CBC in Perl for Ruby?

Note: This problem similar to PHP/Perl at [stackoverflow:655691](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655691/php-pear-encrypting-with-cryptcbc-decrypting-with-perls-cbc).

**Perl Version**

```
use Crypt::CBC;
use MIME::Base64::Perl;

my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
    -key    => "95A8EE8E89979B9EFDCBC6EB9797528D",
    -keysize => 32, 
    -cipher => "Crypt::OpenSSL::AES"
  );  

$encypted = $cipher->encrypt("ABCDEFGH12345678");
$base64 = encode_base64($encypted);

print("$base64"); # output -> U2FsdGVkX18m1jVqRTxANhcEj6aADeOn+2cccDft2eYAMfOkYCvAAkTIOv01VHc/

$de_base64 = decode_base64($base64);
$decrypted = $cipher->decrypt($de_base64);
$c = $cipher->finish;
print("$decrypted \n");
```

My ruby version looks like this:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128.new("CBC")
aes.encrypt
aes.key = "95A8EE8E89979B9EFDCBC6EB9797528D"

encypted = aes.update("ABCDEFGH12345678") + aes.final
base64 = Base64.encode64(encypted)

puts base64 # outout -> gx1K24LqlRUtNNTDNUJTyn7HrVKK6UkfNA9LNpNjZeE=
```

I'm pretty sure Base64 work same in Ruby and Perl. Any clue what is the right way to do?

**Update (Solution)**

```
use Crypt::CBC;
use MIME::Base64;

my $key = "95A8EE8E89979B9E";
my $iv = "1234567890abcdef";

my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
                  -key        => $key,
                  -cipher     => 'Rijndael',
                  -iv         => $iv,
                  -literal_key => 1,
                  -padding => 'null',
                  -keysize => 128/8,
                  -header     => 'none'
                  );  
my $plaintext = $cipher->encrypt("Hello");
print encode_base64($plaintext); # output -> kJCpQC0+iNF8exHGx3GLYw==
```

Ruby

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-128-cbc")
aes.decrypt
aes.key = "95A8EE8E89979B9E"
aes.iv = "1234567890abcdef"
aes.padding = 0

base64 = Base64.decode64("kJCpQC0+iNF8exHGx3GLYw==")
decrypted = aes.update(base64)
decrypted << aes.final

puts decrypted # guess? It is "Hello"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have something the same for Perl and php.

http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/FAYLAND/OpenSocialX-Shindig-Crypter-0.03/sample/crypt.pl
http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/FAYLAND/OpenSocialX-Shindig-Crypter-0.03/sample/crypt.php

and there is a tip for you:

```
my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
    {
        'key'         => 'length16length16',
        'cipher'      => 'Rijndael',
        'iv'          => '1234567890abcdef',
        'literal_key' => 1,
        'padding'     => 'null',
        'header'      => 'none',
        keysize       => 128 / 8
    }
);
```

key must be length 16. and better the length of iv is 16 chars too.

I hope it helps.

Thanks.